# 'Any' result set for Exposed Filter w/ limited list is not limited

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have an exposed filter for a taxonomy vocabulary. The filter settings are

- **Single Filter**
- *Operator:* **Is one of**
- *Limit list to selected items:* **On**
- *Selected vocabulary terms:* a subset of the full, flat (non-hierarchal) vocabulary

  - Assume selected terms `term1`, `term2`, `term3`
  - Assume non selected terms `non1`, `non2`, `non3`

The filters UI appears and is accurate, and it is functional when a filter is selected. However, when the `- Any -` option is selected, all objects from the vocabulary are displayed - all of the `term#` objects are displayed along with the `non#` objects.

I've tried adding a second (non-exposed) filter that does `is one of` for each of the `term#` terms. With this, the `- Any -` option is correct but none of the other selected filters in the drop down work.

**How do I get only the selected `term#` elements to show when the `- Any -` option is selected?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second non-exposed filter change the operator to `is none of`and assign the terms accordingly (inverse to what you have now). If not otherwhise specified filters in views are `AND` filters.

Comment: You're my hero. What's your address? I'll mail you a beer ;)

Comment: You're very welcome!